# Image Width Resizing bug (Default Image Resizes, but Article-Associated Image Stays at 900 Instead of 300)

Tags: next.js, graphql

I have an issue with the width resizing of my images. When I load the default image, resizing occurs. However, when I load an image associated with an article, the desired resizing doesn't happen, and it remains at 900 instead of 300.

The image is supposed to be displayed using the <**FeaturedImage**> component in my page template at pages/blog/index.js.

```js
import FeaturedImage from "@/components/FeaturedImage";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import SiteHeader from "@/components/SiteHeader";
import getAllPosts from "@/lib/posts";

/* Fonction asynchrone pour récupérer les données des articles */
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const allPosts = await getAllPosts();
  return {
    props: {
      allPosts: allPosts,
    },
  };
}

/* Définition du composant principal de la page de blog */
export default function BlogHome({ allPosts }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Blog</title>
      </Head>
      <div className="h-[50vh] min-h-[20rem] bg-[url('/home.jpg')] relative">
        <div className="absolute bg-slate-900 inset-0 z-0 opacity-40"></div>
        <SiteHeader className="header-blog-home z-10 relative" />
        <h1 className="text-6xl text-center text-slate-100 relative z-10 py-8">
          BLOG
        </h1>
        <p className="relative z-10 text-center text-slate-200 text-2xl">
          Read our latest articles
        </p>
      </div>
      <main>
        <section className="post-list mt-4">
          <ul>
            {/* Mapping de la liste des articles récupérée */}
            {allPosts.nodes.map((post) => (
              <li key={post.slug} className="grid grid-col-5 gap-4 mb-4">
                <div className="col-span-2">
                  {/* Affiche de l'image à la une de l'article */}
                  <FeaturedImage post={post} />
                  {/*console.log(
                    post.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.sizes[0].sourceUrl
                  )*/}
                </div>
                <div className="col-span-3">
                  <h2 className="py-4">
                    <Link
                      href={`/blog/${post.slug}`}
                      className="text-blue-400 text-2xl"
                    >
                      {post.title}
                    </Link>
                  </h2>
                  {/* affiche le contenu de l'extrait d'un article de manière sécurisée en utilisant React */}
                  <div
                    className="text-lg"
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.excerpt }}
                  ></div>
                  {/* affiche les categories de l'article avec un liens*/}
                  <div>
                    Posted under {/* affiche post under ou publié sous*/}
                    {post.categories.nodes.map((category) => (
                      <Link
                        href={`/category/${category.slug}`}
                        key={category.slug}
                        className="text-blue-400 hover:text-blue-500"
                      >
                        {category.name}
                      </Link>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </section>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

`components\FeaturedImage.js`

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

// Composant fonctionnel "FeaturedImage" qui prend un objet "post" en tant que paramètre
export default function FeaturedImage({ post }) {
  let img = "";

  // URL de l'image par défaut en cas de manque d'image dans "post"
  const defaultFeaturedImage =
    "http://nextjstest1.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/travel_icy-polar_022K.jpg";

  // Dimensions par défaut pour l'image
  const defaultWidth = "300";
  const defaultHeight = "200";

  // Affiche les données de post pour le débogage
  console.log("Données de post :", post);
  console.log(post.featuredImage);
  console.log("url" + post.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.sizes[0].sourceUrl);

  // Vérifie si "post" a une image en vedette ("FeaturedImage")
  if (post.FeaturedImage) {
    // Si oui, récupère la première taille de l'image dans les détails multimédias
    let size = post.FeaturedImage.node.mediaDetails.sizes[0];
    img = {
      src: size.sourceUrl,
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
    };
    // Si "post" n'a pas d'image en vedette, utilise l'image et les dimensions par défaut
  } else
    img = {
      src: defaultFeaturedImage,
      width: defaultWidth,
      height: defaultHeight,
    };
  // Retourne un composant "Link" de Next.js avec une image liée
  return (
    <Link href={`/blog/${post.slug}`}>
      <Image
        src={img.src}
        width={img.width}
        height={img.height}
        alt={post.title}
      />
    </Link>
  );
}
```

My query is : `lib\graphqlRequest.js`

```js
export default async function graphqlRequest(query) {
  // URL de l'API GraphQL que nous allons interroger
  const url = "http://nextjstest1.local/graphql";
  // En-têtes de la requête HTTP pour spécifier que nous envoyons des données au format JSON.
  const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };

  // Effectue une requête POST asynchrone vers l'URL spécifiée avec les en-têtes
  // et le corps de la requête fournis.
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    headers,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(query),
  });

  // Attend la réponse de la requête HTTP et la convertit en objet JSON.
  const resJson = await res.json();
  // Retourne la réponse JSON. Notez que cette fonction est asynchrone,
  // ce qui signifie qu'elle renvoie une promesse résolue avec la réponse JSON.
  return resJson;
}
```

and my `next.config.js`

```js
{
  /*
- next/image pour effectuer un certain nombre de vérifications pour s'assurer que les images sont sûres et provenant de sources approuvées.
- remotePatterns vous permet de spécifier les modèles d'URLs d'images distantes qui sont autorisés dans votre application.
*/
}
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true, //option qui aide à identifier des problèmes potentiels dans votre application
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "nextjstest1.local",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a CSS problem ...

I have to put
`<li key={post.slug} className="grid grid-cols-5 gap-4 mb-4">`

instead that
I written `<li key={post.slug} className="grid grid-col-5 gap-4 mb-4">`

I had to add the s at `cols-5`

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have the output of your `console.log(post.featuredImage)` debugging statement.

This doesn't appear to be a GraphQL issue - all your sizing logic is here:

```
  if (post.FeaturedImage) {
    let size = post.FeaturedImage.node.mediaDetails.sizes[0];
    img = {
      src: size.sourceUrl,
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
    };
  } else
    img = {
      src: defaultFeaturedImage,
      width: defaultWidth,
      height: defaultHeight,
    };
```

If your image is coming out at a size other than 300x200 it means you had to go through the first branch of that `if` statement which means that `post.FeaturedImage` is true-ish.

Also weird that you have `width` and `height` as strings but without units.

`width: 300` makes sense as does `width: "300px"` but `width: "300"`?

> TIL that "debugging" in French is "débogage" ;)